# Protractor test failins on different screen resolution

Tags: protractor

I have a simple test which check width

```
labelBackground.getAttribute('width').then(function (width) {
        expect(width).toBe('60');
    });
```

It's working for me but fails for my colleague whose screen resolution is different. 
I've tried played with config and setting screen size in before each but it didn't help.

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1000, 1000);
```

What is the way of solving this issue? 
Thank you!

Comment: `browser.manage().window().setSize(1000, 1000);` should work.

Comment: That was the answer, thanks)

Comment: Cool! added it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
browser.manage().window().setSize(1000, 1000);
```